# Map is not displayed properly using Google Map API

Tags: google-api

I have struggled with the issue to display the map with the location using Google Map API. As you see the result page, it shows the data from backend properly like **house_lan** and **house_lng**, but the map with the location is not shown up. Could you tell me what I missed up?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Local Schools</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initMap() {
          new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: {{house.lat}}, lng: {{house.lng}}},
                zoom: 16
              });
            }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>{{house.id}}</h1>
      <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
      {{house.lat}} ---- {{house.lng}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. In my case, I assigned wrong values into latitude, longitude backwardly. After revising it, it has shown up properly.